How Do I Apply CSS To An APEX Interactive Report Based Upon Universal Theme Chosen?
I have an Oracle APEX 23.1 Application where I have defined 2 different Universal Themes, Blue and Pink. These themes are based upon the Vita theme.
I have several Interactive Reports in my application, however the theme styling seems to apply to only certain parts of the Interactive Report. For example, the report headers don't appear to be styled with my theme settings.
I found another web article that explains how to style with css the headers of an interactive report:
.a-IRR-table th { background-color: #eedef0; color: #000000; }
I put the above css in the page level css of each page that has an interactive report in the Inline CSS property.
However, if I want to switch between the Blue and Pink themes while running the application, this does not work, as I set the colors in the css specific to only one of the themes.
How can I style the interactive report based upon the theme that is currently being used in the running application?
I have not tried using JavaScript yet. Is there a way to use Javascript to conditionally style a page?

Have a look at this older answer. Instead of hardcoding a color and background color you could just have the theme get the relevant color combo.

The theme roller has a space for this custom css. This will be a distinct value for each theme style.

Thanks! Do you know which property in the theme roller I can use to specify this?

Custom css .. it's at the end or bottom

Please mark answered to help others
